# Magento 2 - Add custom attribute to custom section admin

Tags: magento2, module, admin, admin-panel, custom-attributes

I installed my "customsection_adminbackend" module which adds a new menu item in the Magento 2 backend.
For now in this new section there is only a text "Hello world", but I would like to insert / install some custom attributes in this section of the backend.

What I would like to do is more or less this:

```
$myCustomSection->addAttribute(
         \Magento\CustomSection\AdminBackend::ENTITY, 'descCate1', [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Descrizione categoria 1',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'required' => false,
            'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
            'sort_order' => 150,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
         ]
         );
```

Finally I would like to be able to add the shop filter to my custom section of the backend.
I found this code but I don't know where to put it:

```
<filters name="listing_filters">
        <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options"/>
                <caption translate="true">All Store Views</caption>
                <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </filterSelect>
    </filters>
```

The final result I would like to see in my backend custom section is this:
[image]

How can I go about installing the two attributes and filter for store view in my custom module?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the XML file of the ""customersection_adminbacked"" module then insert your desired field and the original module

Declare the original module in the sequence section of your custom module so that you can override the XML file